# Try except block

Tags: python, dictionary, try-except

How could I code this in python "try except" block?
I have a dictionary (key and Values) the values are integer.
In a "try except" block, I am to enter keys of my choice and the value will sum up.
I am exiting with my last input. With "ctrl +d" and then the program should give me the sum of the value of keys entered.

```
fruits = {
    "mango": 4.00, "lemon": 2.00,
    "orange": 3.00, "apple": 2.00,
    "avocado": 2.50, "pineapple": 5.00,
    "Watermelon": 6.50, "grapes": 4.5
    }
price = 0
while True:
    try:
        n = input("Order: ")

        if n in fruits:
            price += fruits.get(n)

    except(EOFError, KeyboardInterrupt):
        print(f"Sum of inputs is: {price}")
        break
```

That is my code above.

What is wrong with that code?

I am not getting what I want.

I do not want the program to prompt me before I quit with "control + d". I want to quit when entering my last key. Then the program would print the sum of values for me.

Comment: I don't think you can have both the `input()` returning *and* get a `KeyboardInterrupt` at the same time. Your `try/except` says as much. It will either process the next input and loop round again, **or** it will process the exception.

Comment: As a side note - `sum` is built-in function, don't use it as name

Comment: I made the necessary correction (sum)

Comment: `Cntrl`+`D` works oly in Unix envs. Is that you want ?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use exception to handle control-flow in your code. Use conditions to leave the loop.

> I do not want the program to prompt me before I quit with "control + d". I want to quit when entering my last key.

is not possible - the program "loops too fast" for you to be able to quit it *right* when you sum up values - unless you force the program to [sleep()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.sleep) for some time after you sum up the values:

```
from time import sleep

fruits = {"mango": 4.00, "lemon": 2.00, "orange": 3.00, "apple": 2.00,
    "avocado": 2.50, "pineapple": 5.00, "watermelon": 6.50, "grapes": 4.5}

cost = 0
while True:
    try:
        n = input("Order: ")
    
        if n not in fruits:
            print("Invalid choice.")

        # sum if in dict, else use 0
        cost += fruits.get(n, 0) 
        
        sleep(2) # force a 2 second pause _every_ time to allow Ctrl-D/C
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        break

print(f"Sum of inputs is: {cost}")
```

This is *ugly* though - the far better choice is to handle empty inputs as "I am done...":

```
fruits = {"mango": 4.00, "lemon": 2.00, "orange": 3.00, "apple": 2.00,
    "avocado": 2.50, "pineapple": 5.00, "watermelon": 6.50, "grapes": 4.5}

cost = 0

print( *(f"{n} costs {p}" for n,p in fruits.items()), sep="\n")

while True:
    n = input("Order: ")
   
    if not n:    # empty string is "Falsy" - same as most empty 
        break    # iterables, 0, and some other values

    if n not in fruits:
        print("Invalid choice.")

    cost += fruits.get(n, 0)     # add 0 if not in dict


print(f"Sum of inputs is: {cost}")
```

to get

```
mango costs 4.0
lemon costs 2.0
orange costs 3.0
apple costs 2.0
avocado costs 2.5
pineapple costs 5.0
Watermelon costs 6.5
grapes costs 4.5

Order: lemon
Order: water                   # invalid choice
Invalid choice.
Order: grapes
Order:                         # empty input breaks 
Sum of inputs is: 6.5          # 2 + 4.5
```

You should not use `sum` as variable name, the name is taken by the build in `sum()` function.

Exceptions are there to handle errors, not to steer your code's flow.

Comment: I like your idea.
please, It is part of a project I am working on and I am to use "ctrl +d" with "try -except" block

Answer (score -1):

You can use `finally` to print the final price in the end

```
fruits = {
"mango": 4.00, "lemon": 2.00,
"orange": 3.00, "apple": 2.00,
"avocado": 2.50, "pineapple": 5.00,
"Watermelon": 6.50, "grapes": 4.5
}

price = 0

while True:
try:
    n = input("Order: ")
    price += fruits[n]
    print("Item added.")

except:
    print("Item is not in the list.")

finally:
    print("Sum: " + str(price))
```

and also you can print empty string after printing sum for better interface

```
fruits = {
"mango": 4.00, "lemon": 2.00,
"orange": 3.00, "apple": 2.00,
"avocado": 2.50, "pineapple": 5.00,
"Watermelon": 6.50, "grapes": 4.5
}

price = 0

while True:
    try:
        n = input("Order: ")
        price += fruits[n]
        print("Item added.")

    except:
        print("Item is not in the list.")

    finally:
        print("Sum: " + str(price))
        print("")
```

if you want to get the sum at the end you can print it outside of `while`

```
fruits = {
"mango": 4.00, "lemon": 2.00,
"orange": 3.00, "apple": 2.00,
"avocado": 2.50, "pineapple": 5.00,
"Watermelon": 6.50, "grapes": 4.5
}

price = 0

while True:

    try:
        n = input("Order: ")
        price += fruits[n]
        print("Item added.")

    except:
        print("Item is not in the list.")
        break

print("Sum: " + str(price))
```

Comment: It is part of a project I am working on and I am to use "ctrl +d" with "try -except" block.

Comment: Your 1st code block is misaligned.  Your first and second code can not be left at all - neither with CTRL-D nor by any other means due to catching **all** exceptions from inside the program. Your first 2 code blocks print the sum on every input, not after all inputs as specified. Your last code does not loop on invalid inputs as the original solution does.